# Looking for a MACRO adding two characters together for switch cases

Tags: c++, macros, static, switch-statement, character

I'm working on an old network engine and the type of package sent over the network is made up of 2 bytes.

This is more or less human readable form, for example "LO" stands for Login.

In the part that reads the data there is an enormous switch, like this:

```
short sh=(((int)ad.cData[p])<<8)+((int)ad.cData[p+1]);
switch(sh)
{
    case CMD('M','D'):
    ..some code here
    break
```

where CMD is a define:

```
#define CMD(a,b) ((a<<8)+b)
```

I know there are better ways but just to clean up a bit and also to be able to search for the tag (say "LO") more easily (and not search for different types of "'L','O'" or "'L' , 'O'" or the occasional "'L', 'O'" <- spaces make it hard to search) I tried to make a MACRO for the switch so I could use "LO" instead of the define but I just can't get it to compile.

**So here is the question: how do you change the #define to a macro that I can use like this instead:**

```
case CMD("MD"):
..some code here
break
```

It started out as a little subtask to make life a little bit easier but now I can't get it out of my head, thanks for any help!

Cheers!

[edit] The code works, it the world that's wrong! ie. Visual Studio 2010 has a bug concerning this. No wonder I cut my teeth on it.

Comment: Does it have to be a macro? I'd have thought a `constexpr` function would be the way to go, although it may require a very recent compiler.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a macro if there is anything else that might work but I'm on MSVC 2010 so no constexpr... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Macro-based solution

A *string-literal* is really an instance of `char const[N]` where `N` is the length of the string, including the terminating *null-byte*. With this in mind you can easily access any character within the *string-literal* by using `string-literal[idx]` to specify that you'd like to read the character stored at offset `idx`.

```
#define CMD(str) ((str[0]<<8)+str[1])
```

```
CMD("LO") => (("LO"[0]<<8)+"LO"[1]) => (('L'<<8)+'0')
```

You should however keep in mind that there's nothing preventing your from using the above macro with a string which is shorter than that of length `2`, meaning that you can run into *undefined-behavior* if you try to read an offset which is not actually valid.

---

#### RECOMMENDED: *C++11*, use a constexpr function

You could create a function usable in *constant-expressions* (and with that, in case-labels), with a parameter of *reference to const char[3]*, which is the *"real"* type of your string-literal *"FO"*.

```
constexpr short cmd (char const(&ref)[3]) {
  return (ref[0]<<8) + ref[1];
}
```

```
int main () {
  short data = ...;

  switch (data) {
    case cmd("LO"):
      ...
  }
}
```

---

#### *C++11* and [user-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)

In C++11 we were granted the possibility to define user-defined literals. This will make your code far easier to maintain and interpret, as well as having it be safer to use:

```
#include <stdexcept>

constexpr short operator"" _cmd (char const * s, unsigned long len) {
  return len != 2 ? throw std::invalid_argument ("") : ((s[0]<<8)+s[1]);
}
```

```
int main () {
  short data = ...;

  switch (data) {
   case "LO"_cmd:
     ...
  }
}
```

The value associated with a *case-label* must be yield through a constant-expression. It might look like the above might throw an exception during runtime, but since a *case-label* is constant-expression the compiler **must** be able to evaluate `"LO"_cmd` during translation.

If this is not possible, as in `"FOO"_cmd`, the compiler will issue a diagnostic saying that the code is ill-formed.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, unfortunately I'm on MSVC 2010 and thus has not access to C++11 and the (old & unsafe) code is what doesn't work for me. It gives me this error: error C2051: case expression not constant

Comment: @Valmond are you saying that the *macro solution* doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work and gives the error C2051. It's like having a function call (and thus MSVC can't pre-evaluate the value for the swotch/case), well that's my interpretation of the error anyway...
Maybe it's a compiler switch or whatever that I need to change but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Valmond in other words; *msvc* is doing it wrong, the current answer currently holds. if you got questions regarding a workaround to the apparent bug in *msvc* you should form another question.

Comment: @Valmond also, it's not related to the macro "behaving like having a function call", msvc doesn't accept string-literals to be used in constant-expressions; something that it shall.

Comment: @Valmond I don't have access to *msvc* right now, but play with multi-character literals and you should be able to figure something out.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I just didn't get why I couldn't get it to work :-) With multi characters, do you mean like using a wchar_t or something? I'll play around with it and see if I can work around it...

Comment: @Valmond You should accept the answer in this question since it answers what you asked (that you cannot do it in vc++ is because of a bug, the solutions posted are valid in terms of being Standard C++), but anyhow; here's [the hack](http://rextester.com/VYLB7753) I was talking about, use it carefully.